# Exclude a a directory in php open_basedir on nginx webserver

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I am trying to set a php `open_basedir` for my website , I have only 2 locations to execute my php script and I  need to disable php on a sub folder inside the document root. I don't know if this is possible.

are the doc roots requires php execution

```
/home/bastian/html
/home/bastian/meatalheavy
```

I need to disable php exection on the following dirs

```
/home/bastian/html/ass_ests
/home/bastian/html/images/
```

**php.ini**

```
open_basedir = "/home/bastian/html" ; "/home/bastian/meatalheavy"
```

Comment: It's not about programming, it's about administration

Comment: @Hnatt: It's okay to ask programming related administration questions on SO.

Comment: Sorry, took my "-1" back

Answer (score 0):

The setting of [`open_basedir` <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) sets access to a directory *tree*, not a specific directory. So if you'd like to restrict a subdirectory, you must not allow any of it's parents.

**Note:** Depending on your directory layout (and PHP version) it looks like that what you want to do is **not possible** or at least not w/o a large amount of configuration (allowing all files and subfolder individually).

Answer (score 0):

The open_basedir setting should be written like that:

```
open_basedir = "/home/bastian/html:/home/bastian/meatalheavy"
```

This will effectively not prevent execution of php scripts on subdirectories, it will also allow inclusion of php scripts (`include[_once]`, `require[_once]` from subdirectories of the open_basedir. But you may need som other paths in your open basedir, any external PHP library used on the temporary directory (especially for uploads), or the session.save_path.

```
open_basedir = "/home/bastian/html:/home/bastian/meatalheavy:/var/lib/php5/:/path/to/my/php/defined/temporary/dir:/path/to/my/session/dir"
```

So this will be ok for inclusion (no way to remove a subtree from inclusion), now to prevent php execution on some subdirectories you simply need to prevent direct access to a php script there (not the same thing as backend in-php access). For Nginx this should be ok:

```
location ~* ^/(ass_ests|images)/.*\.(php|php5)$
{
    deny all;
}
```

but you could also play with the mim type as described in [this blog post](http://www.whoila.com/blog/?p=1899). where the content of the image directory is forced to images, so that even a script with an image extension will not be executed. In FastCgi mode some PHP execution  in images files was available.
So for your image directory (don't knwo what you have in the other one) this would be

```
    location /images/
    {
            types
            {
                    image/gif       gif;
                    image/jpeg      jpeg jpg;
                    image/png       png;
                    text/plain      txt;
            }
            default_type    application/octet-stream;
            location ~ \.(php|php5)$
            {
                    break;
            }
    }
```